# getCollection() return false in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, database

class Mage_Customer_Model_Designs file

```
function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer_designs/customer');
}
```

class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Designs file

```
protected function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer_designs/customer','d_id');
}
```

class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Designs_Collection file

```
protected function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer_designs/customer');
}
```

class Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard_Designs file

```
function get_my_designs()
{
 return $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/designs')->getCollection();
}
```

Table Name: customer_designs, Table Prefix: djc

These are all my codes. My Blog file returns bool(false).  I just replaced existing code. I don't know how these codes are all codes working. Kindly help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivek Aasaithambi,I did not understand why you have doing this type of code.

**Issue 1:**
Why you have write `your class at Core class it too wrong process`.If you have create a new module then `you should create custom module with database`.
see at http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

**Issue 2:**

If you have write this type code.then there  are lot of issues.

model construct is to wrong

**class Mage_Customer_Model_Designs file**

```
function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer/designs');
}
```

**class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Designs file**

```
protected function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer/designs','d_id');
}
```

**class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Designs_Collection file**

```
protected function _construct()
{
  $this->_init('customer/designs');
}
```

**I Guess that there must be lot of issue in your code**

### I suggest you please use issue 1 as good solution.

Comment: Hi, I need to add some features in customer dashboard. So only I added code in core code pool. If I put my module in community code pool, can I access in customer dashboard